# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException while dexing with newrelic transformation

Tags: android, gradle, newrelic

I have a Library project which I am trying to use in my DemoApp.

My integration of the Library project into the DemoApp fails if NewRelic is added into the DemoApp build.gradle, as the Dexing is failing after the NewRelic transformation which successfully happens if I don't use NewRelic.

**Following is the build error**

```
    MacBook-Pro:Project admin$ ./gradlew clean;
    > Configure project :DemoApp
    google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 11.4.2 will be used.
    please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
    Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
    2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date


    MacBook-Pro:Project admin$ ./gradlew --stacktrace --scan build;
    > Configure project :DemoApp
    google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 11.4.2 will be used.
    please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
    Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

    > Task :DemoApp:processDebugGoogleServDcesApp
    Parsing json file: /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/google-services.json
    /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-sw600dp-v13/values-sw600dp-v13.xml:74: warn: ignoring configuration 'sw600dp-v13' for styleable PagerIndicator.
    /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-sw600dp-v13/values-sw600dp-v13.xml:116: warn: ignoring configuration 'sw600dp-v13' for styleable SliderLayout.
    /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-sw600dp-v13/values-sw600dp-v13.xml:150: warn: ignoring configuration 'sw600dp-v13' for styleable Themes.


    > Task :DemoApp:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDDbugApp
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/build/intermediates/transforms/newrelicTransform/debug/14.jar
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
            at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:149)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
            at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:401)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:390)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:373)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:79)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:210)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
            at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
            at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
            at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/admin/Project/DemoApp/build/intermediates/transforms/newrelicTransform/debug/14.jar
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
    Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
            at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
            at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst(ArrayDeque.java:285)
            at java.util.ArrayDeque.pop(ArrayDeque.java:522)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarState.pop(JarState.java:740)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1308)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.updateState(JarSourceCode.java:1194)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.computeBlockEntryJarStates(JarSourceCode.java:433)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.JarSourceCode.buildPrelude(JarSourceCode.java:364)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRBuilder.build(IRBuilder.java:569)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuild(JarCode.java:215)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuildWithLocals(JarCode.java:177)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.internalBuildPossiblyWithLocals(JarCode.java:163)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.buildIR(JarCode.java:128)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexEncodedMethod.buildIR(DexEncodedMethod.java:323)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.rewriteCode(IRConverter.java:839)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodToDex(IRConverter.java:502)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertMethodsToDex$3(IRConverter.java:490)
            at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexClass.forEachMethod(DexClass.java:261)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertMethodsToDex(IRConverter.java:486)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.lambda$convertClassesToDex$2(IRConverter.java:471)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:258)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:56)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:471)
            at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertToDex(IRConverter.java:381)
            at com.android.tools.r8.D8.optimize(D8.java:238)
            at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:179)
            at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:97)
            at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
            at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
            at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
            at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
            ... 7 more
            Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
                    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:531)
                    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:492)
                    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:83)
                    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ThreadUtils.awaitFutures(ThreadUtils.java:21)
                    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.IRConverter.convertClassesToDex(IRConverter.java:473)
                    ... 15 more
            [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.util.NoSuchElementException]


    > Task :DemoApp:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    BUILD FAILED in 35s
```

**Following is my Build config**

***Library Project build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        //classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:2.0.0" // For SpotBugs

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***Library Module build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName libraryVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
```

***DemoApp Project build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
                mavenCentral()
                maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
                classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
                classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
                classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:2.0.0" // For SpotBugs
                classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.+"
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
                maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
                flatDir {
                    dirs 'libs'
                }
            }
        }

        task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
        }
```

***DemoApp module build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0"

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation(name:'AndroidSDK-release', ext:'aar') // Library depedency
    implementation "com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.23.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***Library Progaurd rules:***

```
#-printmapping out.map
-keepparameternames
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod

# Preserve all annotations.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and
# methods.

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

# Preserve all .class method names.

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Why I am seeing the `CIRCULAR REFERENCE:java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception while Dexing. This happens only if NewRelic is added to build otherwise the DemoApp build is getting succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a D8/R8 bug affecting `newrelic` versions before `5.24.2`. You must use `com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.24.2` or newer.

See the discussion here:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/dexing-fails-with-com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivebuilderexception-with-newrelic-transformation/78405/7